# D Classes, OOP and GTKd Notebook

Tags: d, gtkd

I am trying to append a page to a gtk notebook using gtkd from the second class (MyNewClass) below. The notebook is created within the first class, main_window and is called by the second. The program compiles fine, however when I open the program the gtk mainwindow is blank except for the tester box.

```
import gtk.Box;
import gtk.Button;
import gtk.Grid;
import gtk.Label;
import gtk.MainWindow;
import gtk.Main;
import gtk.Notebook;

class main_window : MainWindow
{
  Notebook notebook;

  this()
  {
super("MyProg");
    setDefaultSize(600,100);

       //Here is the creation of the notebook
 this.notebook=new Notebook;

Box tester=new Box(Orientation.VERTICAL, 1);  
notebook.appendPage(tester, new Label("test")); //This works fine from this class

 Grid grid=new Grid();
 grid.setColumnSpacing(12);  //establish the main grid
 grid.setRowSpacing(3);
 grid.attach(notebook, 0,0,1,9);
add(grid);
showAll();
  }
}

class MyNewClass : main_window
{
    this()
    {
File MFile = File("file.txt", "r");

    Grid MGrid;
  int row=0;
 int col=0;  //Set the column and row number for the gtk grid.
  string[] list;
 string i;
float p;
Label MLabel;


          while(!MFile.eof)
          {
             if (match(line, `\[\[`)){
             MGrid=new Grid();
        MGrid.setColumnSpacing(12);
         MGrid.setRowSpacing(3);
             row=0;

             line=replace(line, regex(r"(\[)", "g"), "");
            line=replace(line, regex(r"(\])", "g"), "");

                //I HAVE USED A TEST WRITELN HERE TO MAKE SURE THE FUNCTION IS CALLED.
                //Below is the notebook append that fails. When I test it from the first class above, I can append. When I call it here, it compiles but nothing is done.

                Box MBox=new Box(Orientation.VERTICAL, 1);
                MBox.add(MGrid);
         super.notebook.appendPage(MBox, new Label(line));//
          }
      }
}

void main(string[] args)
{
Main.init(args);
new main_window;

new M;
Main.run();
}
```

Comment: If you provide minimal compilable code then it would be easier for us to help.

Comment: No problem. It has been changed to have a more complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the code doesn't compile, but the reason your pages are not showing is that you need to call `MBox.show()` to show the boxes.

```
Box MBox = new Box(Orientation.VERTICAL, 1);
MBox.add(MGrid);
super.notebook.appendPage(MBox, new Label(line));
MBox.show();
```

You can also call `showAll` on a container widget to show all children widgets. In your case, that's the notebook, the grid containing the notebook or the main window. So you can add `notebook.showAll()` after the loop to achieve the same thing.

On a side note, you might want to follow the D style for writing D code: http://dlang.org/dstyle.html.